# Is there a way to print the sum of randomly generated numbers in a do while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, random, numbers

I am writing a program to very fundamentally simulate a black jack game using rand() % 11. We have to tell the players their running total as well as asking if they want another card (hit). My first problem is getting multiple random numbers and my second problem is not being able to add the two random numbers together. Strings are not allowed. Here's the block of code that I think is causing there's errors. I am very new to c++. Do I need to have multiple variables with the rand() %10 +1 to add them? I know that the add + add won't work but I can't figure out an alternative.

```
int add = rand() % 10 + 1;                                                  
bool hit = false;                                                           
int i = 0;                                                                  
       
do {                                                                                     
    cout << "Players 1 running total is " << add;                                          
    i++;                                                                        
    cout << " \n ";                                                             
    cout << "Would you like another number? (0-yes or 1-no) ";                  
    cin >> hit;                                                             
    if ( hit == 0 ) {                                                           
        cout << " You got an " << add << " \n ";                            
        cout << "You're running total is " << add + add;                                       
    }                                                                       
                                                                                   
} while ( hit == false );
```

Comment: @Peter Adding the language to the title has been discouraged for quite some time in favor of proper tags. That said, OP mentions C++ in the question itself and has tagged it with c++.

Comment: you need to define  int sum = 0 before the do-loop and move the add-calculation plus a sum += add into the do-loop.

Comment: @Peter Added it to title

Comment: @SpencerTheDude Sorry for the confusion. Have not seen the language in the text.

Comment: @Peter okay I added sum = 0, But where would I put add +=sum if not in the cout << "Players running total is " << sum += add;  line ?

Comment: Are you seeding the random number generator by calling `srand(time(nullptr))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is an assignment given by an educator, otherwise, you shouldn't be using `rand()` at all (I don't blame you, I blame the instructor for not keeping up with the language.)

You must call `rand()` again to get a new number and use another variable to store the total:

Sidenote:
You should really declare your variables as close to first use as possible instead of the top of the program.

Also, The variable `i` isn't being used in this context so I removed it.

```cpp
srand(time(0)); //Should be nullptr, but instructor probably doesn't know that.
int total = 0;
bool hit = false;
do {
    int add = rand() % 10 + 1;
    total += add;
    cout << "\nYou got an " << add << " \n ";
    cout << "\nPlayer 1 running total is " << total;
    cout << "\nWould you like another number? (0-yes or 1-no) ";
    cin >> hit;
} while (hit == false);
cout << "Player 1 final total is: " << total << endl;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you that helped a lot, I don't just want to put this in and call it good I'd really like to learn a little more about it. First the srand is srand(time(NULL)) just thought I'd clarify that, also could you explain a little more to me on why the add variable is now able to produce multiple random numbers instead of just repeating the same one?

Comment: also since you removed I++ does that mean do/while loops do not need a pre increment or post increment to run?

Comment: @SpencerTheDude Correct. `while` and `do-while` loops only depend on the conditional expression inside the parenthesis. The variable must exist outside the loop however. (I just now noticed this error and have fixed it.)

Comment: @SpencerTheDude The `add` variable is able to produce multiple random numbers because the function `rand()` is being called every loop and then being stored in `add` during its construction and initialization.

Comment: @TheDude Welcome. If this answer solved your question, please mark it as Accepted by clicking the check mark in the upper left.